# kivy Unable to get any Image provider, abort

Tags: python, kivy

here is my error please help..!

```html
from kivy.app import App

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Mihinomo\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-10-28_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers:  (img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif, img_pil ignored)
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get any Image provider, abort.
```

i have installed all dependencies:

```html
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
pip install kivy
```

Comment: You are good, try to run some example apps

Comment: What Python version do you have installed in your PC?

Comment: It's written there above don't you see..  3.4

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to add Bleak module to Kivy and your error looks a lot like the one I am currently dealing with. There are various solutions because the probability for it to be a clash between two modules is high. You can start by checking those posts :

https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/issues/176

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6816

Edit : I have found a quick fix, which is very ugly but works in my case. I made a separate .py file for Bleak functions and for each function I imported the Bleak components I use at the beginning of it.

......................................................................................................................................................................................................

Last Edit : It is a confusion between the modules who overwrite the same ___ import ___ value and they are messing with each other. A fix that looks better is to add the line :

```
from importlib import __import__
```

inside the .py files of kivy that give you the error. For me it was both in ___ init ___.py and factory.py (in the folder Path/to/Python/Python3X/Lib/site-packages/kivy)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install some system library dependencies according to the installation instructions at [kivy.org](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html):

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
    python-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python \
    python-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-devode
```

You probably don't need all of them, but I would start with all the libs and ffmpeg.

Comment: didn't work after installing system library. What might i be doing wrong. If you have any videos/sites that shows how to install on windows 10 64-bit python 3.6(simple and detailed guide). Please share link..